# System.IndexOutOfRangeException error SQL SELECT query unable to read the data selected from my table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, select, messagebox

I have my SELECT statement on SQL and am just trying to view what was retrieved from the table to check if it is working however I have run into a problem!

I am unsure why my code does not work, whenever I try and run the code an error comes up saying: System.IndexOutOfRangeException and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

I'd be very grateful for any help!

```
public partial class CurrentlySetTestForm : Form

{
    Timer loopTimer = new Timer();
    private string CurrentQuestionID { get; set; }
    private string QuestionSpace { get; set; }
    public CurrentlySetTestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CurrentlySetTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string y = GlobalVariableClass.Signedinteacher;

        Convert.ToInt32(y);

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand command18 = new SqlCommand("SELECT MIN([QuestionID]) FROM QuestionStudentAssociation WHERE ( [StudentID]=@Signedinstudent AND [StudentAnswer]=NULL )", connect);
        command18.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Signedinstudent", y);

        var reader = command18.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            CurrentQuestionID = reader["QuestionID"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(CurrentQuestionID);

        }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Where is it breaking? My initial thought is that you are not actually retrieving any information, then you are trying to look at non-existent information. Put a break  on while (reader.Read()), and then examine the contents of reader to see if you have data.

Comment: This is probably not cause of your problem, but I see that you are using NULL comparison wrong. Instead of `[StudentAnswer]=NULL` you should use `[StudentAnswer] IS NULL`. Please see this blog post: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql?  It's just bad form even if it is parameterized.  EF is a much better choice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error comes from this line:

```
CurrentQuestionID = reader["QuestionID"].ToString();
```

Because no field with the Id "QuestionID" is returned from your query, because you are querying for its minimum value `"MIN([QuestionID])"`.

The easiest fix is:

```
 CurrentQuestionID = reader[0].ToString();
```

This uses the index of the value instead of indexing by field name.

An alternative, as suggested by @KasparsOzols is to appropriately name your "MIN" field value by changing your query like this:

```
var qryText = "SELECT MIN([QuestionID]) AS MinQuestionID FROM QuestionStudentAssociation WHERE (StudentID]=@Signedinstudent AND [StudentAnswer] IS NULL)"
SqlCommand command18 = new SqlCommand(qryText, connect);
```

And retrieve your field like this:

```
CurrentQuestionID = reader["MinQuestionID"].ToString();
```

As also pointed out by @KasparsOzols, there was an error in your SQL statement. You cannot check for "NULL" using "=NULL", but by using "IS NULL".

Comment: More correct fix would be `...SELECT MIN([QuestionID]) AS MinQuestionID ...` and change parsing code to `CurrentQuestionID = reader["MinQuestionID"].ToString();`

Comment: I am trying to Select the smallest value of Question ID for my conditions. Am I doing it all right and will your suggestion fix that?

Comment: If you fix NULL comparison issue I mentioned in main question comments, this should work just fine!

Comment: @mot375 yes it will, you may prefer the second alternative that explicitly uses a named "MinQuestionID" field.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help it works now! Okay I shall try the alternative as well!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is your `MIN` function call.  It does not return as the column name QuestionID, and you call it with `reader["QuestionID"]`.  Min returns a unnamed column.  Try

```
SELECT MIN([QuestionID]) as QuestionID FROM QuestionStudentAssociation WHERE ( [StudentID]=@Signedinstudent AND [StudentAnswer]=NULL )
```

That should do it.

Comment: It would work but this is bad naming. Should use more descriptive column name like `MinQuestionID`